# How to access the old edit window after reaching 2k reputation?

Tags: support, edits, user-interface

I just recently hit 2000 reputation and have run into an issue with how I edit questions now, I cannot see past revisions during my edit as it is done in the page still - and this means that I cannot revert bad edits without manually doing the edit.

Is there a way to access the edit page I am used to so that I can still see each revision as well as edit at the same time, or am I stuck with this now?

Comment: Well you can always pull up the revisions in another tab using `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/{post-id}/revisions`.  Also note that from that screen there is a rollback link and you can click on that to rollback the post to that revision instantly.

Comment: BTW, Congrats on getting 2k and edit privileges. You'll really be proud of those :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the edit page using the link `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/{post-id}/edit`, for example https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40550452/edit.

If you want to edit a specific revision, the best way is to go to the revision history, and click the "edit" link on that revision:

[image]

Comment: +1 - I feel really stupid for missing that. I guess it's Friday today.

Answer (score 1):

To revert a bad edit, you can simply use the rollback functionality from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40549483/revisions) of a post, which you can access by clicking the 'edited x mins ago' link of a post.

<s>Once you roll back, you can use the grace period (5 minutes) to make further edits to the post. That will count as a single edit.</s>

The above doesn't work as @animuson notes (and I just double-checked this myself). You can of course refine the post after rolling back, but if you insist on it being a single edit, you can use the 'source' link in the revision history to get the Markdown source of a revision, and use that as the starting point for a regular edit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure further edits cannot ever be collapsed into a rollback edit, only a regular edit.

Comment: @animuson you're right, I just checked this on this very post. Thanks.